# How to write latex command using pandoc variables

Tags: pandoc

I use pandoc template `default.latex` and I would like to custom it to obtain a vertical space between `author.name` and `autor.affiliation`. 
I get a skip line when I use `\\` so I suppose it's possible to insert code but how ?

`$if(author)
$\author{$for(author)$$author.name$\\$author.affiliation$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the vertical space as an option: `\\[2ex]`

```
$if(author)$
\author{$for(author)$$author.name$\\[2ex] $author.affiliation$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$
```

Test file:

```
---
title: The document title
author:
- name: Author One
  affiliation: University of Somewhere
- name: Author Two
  affiliation: University of Nowhere
...

# Test

Lorem...
```

Output:

[image]